# Send stdin keystrokes to channel without newline required

Tags: go, channel

I'd like to send the user's keystrokes to a channel directly after each individual keystroke is made to stdin.

I've attempted the code below, but this doesn't give the desired result because the `reader.ReadByte()` method blocks until newline is entered.

```
func chars() <-chan byte {
    ch := make(chan byte)
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    go func() {
        for {           
            char, err := reader.ReadByte()
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            ch <- char
        }
    }()
    return ch
}
```

Thank you for any advice on how might I get each user input character to go immediately to the channel without the need for a newline character.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stdin is line-buffered by default. This means it will not yield any input to you, until a newline is encountered. This is not a Go specific thing.

Having it behave in a non-buffered way is highly platform specific. As Rami suggested, ncurses is a way to do it. Another option is the much lighter [go-termbox](https://github.com/nsf/termbox-go) package.

If you want to do it all manually (on Linux at least), you can look at writing C bindings for [termios](http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios) or do syscalls directly in Go.

How platforms like Windows handle this, I do not know. You can dig into the source code for ncurses or termbox to see how they did it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm glad I asked my question, or I'd have been fruitlessly mucking around trying to get this to work for even longer. In any case, I like the termbox/ncurses suggestions you and Rami mentioned. I'd never considered this approach, but termbox in particular seems very accessible and should do exactly what I want anyway.

Answer (score 5):

If you are on **Linux**, You might want to look at Goncurses package

http://code.google.com/p/goncurses/

It has the function: GetChar() which is what you want.