# Reading from stdin in golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to read from Stdin in Golang as I'm trying to implement a driver for Erlang. I have the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "bufio"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    go func() { 
        stdout := bufio.NewWriter(os.Stdin) 
        p := []byte{121,100,125,'\n'}
        stdout.Write(p)
        }()
    stdin := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    values := make([]byte,4,4)
    for{
        fmt.Println("b")
        if read_exact(stdin) > 0 {
            stdin.Read(values)
            fmt.Println("a")
            give_func_write(values)
        }else{
            continue
        }
    }
}




func read_exact(r *bufio.Reader) int {
    bits := make([]byte,3,3)
    a,_ := r.Read(bits)
    if a > 0 {
        r.Reset(r)
        return 1
    }
    return -1
}

func give_func_write(a []byte) bool {
    fmt.Println("Yahu")
    return true
}
```

However it seems that the `give_func_write` is never reached. I tried to start a goroutine to write to standard input after 2 seconds to test this.

What am I missing here?
Also the line `r.Reset(r)`. Is this valid in go? What I tried to achieve is simply restart the reading from the beginning of the file. Is there a better way?

**EDIT**

After having played around I was able to find that the code is stuck at `a,_ := r.Read(bits)` in the `read_exact` function

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12361325/357705

Comment: @jimt I guess that I will need to have a protocol in which I send a `\n` to make the input work and at the same time discard it when reading it. For testing purposes whats the binary representation of newline? (a better way to phrase this question would be: what is the number that I need to include in my byte slice to have a newline) ?

Comment: 0x0a should do the trick.

Comment: @jimt check my new code. `b` only gets printed once.

Comment: `p := []byte{121,100,125,125,111,100,161,152, 0x0a}`
Check out this example: http://play.golang.org/p/QMOPsPWF7t
You can replace the `stdin` byte buffer with `os.Stdin` on your own system. The playground doesn't allow use of `os.Stdin`.

Comment: Or this one, if you don't like the use of strings as messages: http://play.golang.org/p/rhk8liXmJ4

Comment: @jimt Right. Looking at your examples I modified the code above to have the newline at the end. I don't want the `read` to ever return hence the reason why I wrote the function as I did. The problem is that it doesn't reach  `give_func_write` and what's more it only prints `b` once although it should print it at every iteration of the loop. Is something blocking in this code? I really appreciate your go playground examples and I have used their principle to try to fix my code but it seems as if something is blocking?

Comment: The code above writes the 3 bytes + '\n' to stdin only once. So it stands to reason it's only read once. The goroutine you spin up at the top does this and then exits. Did you intend for it to have a loop?

Comment: @jimt it does indeed only write 4 bytes only once however the full code that should be executed, that is to print 'a' and to run 'give_func_write`, doesn't execute even once.

Comment: You should **never** write to std*in*.

Comment: @DaveC is this what's causing that code to not execute?

Comment: @bula did you get this to work ? Trying to build similar golang driver for erlang but getting "Bad value on output port '#{driver}'" on erlang side :-(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I guess that I will need to have a protocol in which I send a \n to
>   make the input work and at the same time discard it when reading it

No, you don't. Stdin is line-buffered only if it's bound to terminal. You can run your program `prog < /dev/zero` or `cat file | prog`.

> bufio.NewWriter(os.Stdin).Write(p)

You probably don't want to write to `stdin`. See "[Writing to stdin and reading from stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383803/writing-to-stdin-and-reading-from-stdout-unix-linux-c-programming)" for details.

Well, it's not particular clear for me what you're trying to achieve. I'm assuming, that you just want to read data from `stdin` by fixed-size chunks. Use [io.ReadFull](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadFull) for this. Or if you want to use buffers, you can use [Reader.Peek](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.Peek) or [Scanner](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner) to ensure, that specific number of bytes is available. I've changed your program to demonstrate the usage of `io.ReadFull`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    input, output := io.Pipe()

    go func() {
        defer output.Close()
        for _, m := range []byte("123456") {
            output.Write([]byte{m})
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
        }
    }()

    message := make([]byte, 3)
    _, err := io.ReadFull(input, message)
    for err == nil {
        fmt.Println(string(message))
        _, err = io.ReadFull(input, message)
    }
    if err != io.EOF {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

You can easily split it in two programs and test it that way. Just change `input` to `os.Stdin`.