# Read user input dynamically as it is typed in Golang

Tags: input, go, ncurses

I am trying to see if Go is capable of performing logic on user input as it is typed instead of waiting for a carriage return to begin processing.  I utilized NCurses to accomplish this with a small Python game but wasn't sure how to get NCurses functioning with Go.

Right now, I'm using

```
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Select: ")
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    text = strings.Trim(text, "\n\r")
```

but as I said, this does not process until the user hits enter.

I would like to perform a check on whatever the user entered and eliminate the need for a carriage return; hitting one button is sufficient to generate a response.

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360597/send-stdin-keystrokes-to-channel-without-newline-required/

Comment: Assuming you're not the same guy who posted on Google Groups, this link might be helpful. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/P_Hpy7tvf6Q

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I looked more into goncurses and as nifty as it might end up, it looks like there is no "easy" way to do this.  This is for a pet project and if I don't think I'll be able to share it if it relies on goncurses to function.  It would have been cool to build a neat interface in a term though.